# Automatically slash the backslashes in vim

Tags: regex, vim, csh

Can we write functions/subroutines in csh or vim?

Basically, my question is how to slash the backslashes inside a string automatically which we use for search in vim.

Lets say:

Contents of file file_a is:

```
abcd
a/b/c/d
```

Now, if I search 'abcd' inside vim with "/abcd" in command mode, it will match abcd(first line).
And If I search for 'a/b/c/d', it will not match whole of 'a/b/c/d'. It will match only 'a' from 'a/b/c/d'.

To match whole of 'a/b/c/d', I would need to search for `a\/b\/c\/d`. Slashing backslashes is a pain every time you want to search for strings having backslashes inside it. :)

Have anyone of you solved this earlier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vim:

You can search backwards, where the separator is `?` instead of `/`, so `/` does not need to be escaped: `?a/b/c/d`; to move to the next match downwards, use `N`.

Or you can set the search pattern using `:let @/="a/b/c/d"` (this will not move the cursor), then use `n` to go the next match.

You can also define your own command:

```
function! FindSlashed(arg)
  let @/=a:arg
  norm n
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 S call FindSlashed(<q-args>)
```

which you can use like this:

```
:S a/b/c/d
```

EDIT: `let`, not `set`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I knew about the backward search. And that is a tweak, not solution. I will give a try to your second method.

Comment: Of course it is a tweak. The intended way to use the search is to escape the slashes.

Comment: Second option:

I tried setting this `:set @/="a/b/c/d"` but it did not work out. Errors out with : `E518: Unknown option: @/=`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: accepted this answer because of third method. Way to define your own command. This solved the purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my derp. Should be `let`. The function definition even had it correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about searching but about replacing. I thought you might find this helpful as you're writing functions

You can use [alternate delimiters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command) for replace command. ie, rather than using `/`, you can use something like `#`

```
:s#a/b/c/d#this text will replace#
```

The above command will replace `a/b/c/d` with `this text will replace`

Comment: Question was about searching not replacing.

Comment: Yes I understand. I thought this might be useful for someone else reading this post in the future. Let me see if there is something similar in search too